# How to store (and load) a marker into an Entity with Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-app-engine

I want to be able to post a marker onto a GoogleMap and show other posted markers (from other users) in a 50 km radius around me. How would I go about doing that?

Do I have to make a separate class to store the markers (or their properties like Lat Lng) or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [types supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) there is a `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt` that stores latitude and longitude, but you will need to store other attributes (title, alpha, zIndex, visible, ...) in more general types like `String`, `float`, `int`, `boolean`...

Comment: Oh, nice. I'll give GeoPt a try. I assume I'm on the right path with this:                         
    Entity test = new Entity("user");
test.setProperty("location", new GeoPt(lat, lng));
datastore.put(test);

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to implement it . Is it best if I make a separate class for my datastore and use getters from other classes so I can retrieve the information I need?

Comment: Yes. I would create a model class to store all the parameters and a converter to transform between the `Marker` and your class

Comment: Thank you. You've been very helpful! I have one more question and it's a bit tough to word out; if I'm storing my information into an Entity (just like how other users store their information like in the comment I made), could it  overwrite someone elses Entity? I'm just worried about that because we're using the same Entity name and property names. Do I have to make unique Entity name for each user or does App Engine already do that for me?

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities "Each entity in Cloud Datastore has a key that uniquely identifies it". In that link you can see what is a *key* and you can use `getKey()` to get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115879/discussion-between-saltysea-and-antonio).